# SQL Get rows distinct by one column but also distinct on another column ordered by third column

Tags: sql, distinct

I have the following set of data:

[image]

This is an output of a cross join that compares each value on the left with each on the right using a function, but this is somewhat irelevant.

What i need to get from this are two lines, in this particular case i want first and fourth line.

The logic is... i want distinct on column b_index with the highest accu value but not from rows with column a that have allready been used.

So.. first row has to be where b_index = 1, biggest accu for b_index is 95 and all a_index values are available so i want that row. This makes a_index 2 unavailable for next rows

The second b_index is 2, look for all available a_index values, in this case i only have a_index 1 available and i want the row with the highest accu.

I have been using stackoverflow for a long while but this is my fist post so please be kind if i did it wrong :)

Thnk you in advance for any help

UPDATE:

```
CREATE TABLE #example
  ( 
    a_index int,
    b_index int,
    a varchar(max),
    b varchar(max),
    accu int
  ) 


INSERT INTO #example (a_index, b_index, a, b, accu)
    VALUES
        (3,1,'dddd','dddd',95),
        (1,1,'aaaa','dddd',0),
        (2,1,'bbbb','dddd',0),
        (1,2,'aaaa','aaaa',95),
        (3,2,'dddd','aaaa',0),
        (2,2,'bbbb','aaaa',0),
        (1,3,'aaaa','aaaa',95),
        (3,3,'dddd','aaaa',0),
        (2,3,'bbbb','aaaa',0)
```

```
b_index 1 should match a_index 3 because it has the highest accu
b_index 2 should match a_index 1 because it has the highest accu and was not previously used
b_index 3 should match a_index 2 because it is the only one left unused
```

It can also work the other way but the list is presorted to be easyer starting with b_index column

```
a_index 1 -> b_index 3
a_index 3 -> b_index 1 (because a_index 3 has a higher max accu then 2)
a_index 2 -> b_index 2
```

You can ignore columns a and b, they are irelevant

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Comment: If there is a b_index with no unique a_index then that particular b_index should not be selected?

Comment: This feels like a recursive CTE.

Comment: A recursive CTE is probably the solution but i cant figure out how. I am hoping someone with more experience can see the solution.

Comment: Might be easiest as a cursor.  Can't believe I just wrote that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might keep trying to find a recursive CTE solution (I'm still new to rCTE's).  However, I think this CURSOR solution will work:

```
declare @example table
  ( 
    a_index int,
    b_index int,
    a varchar(max),
    b varchar(max),
    accu int
  ) 

INSERT INTO @example (a_index, b_index, a, b, accu)
    VALUES
        (3,1,'dddd','dddd',95),
        (1,1,'aaaa','dddd',0),
        (2,1,'bbbb','dddd',0),
        (1,2,'aaaa','aaaa',95),
        (3,2,'dddd','aaaa',0),
        (2,2,'bbbb','aaaa',0),
        (1,3,'aaaa','aaaa',95),
        (3,3,'dddd','aaaa',0),
        (2,3,'bbbb','aaaa',0)

declare @output table (a_index int, b_index int)
declare @b_index int

declare out_cursor cursor
for
    select distinct b_index
    from @example
    order by b_index
;

open out_cursor

fetch next from out_cursor into @b_index

while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin
        insert into @output
        select min(a_index) a_index, a.b_index
        from (
            select b_index, max(accu) accu
            from @example
            where b_index = @b_index
                and a_index not in (select a_index from @output)
            group by b_index
        ) a
        inner join @example e
            on a.b_index=e.b_index
            and a.accu=e.accu
            and a_index not in (select a_index from @output)
        group by a.b_index

        fetch next from out_cursor into @b_index
    end

close out_cursor
deallocate out_cursor

select *
from @output
```

Comment: Adjusted it to work, you forgot about buggest accu first. But the effort is grately appreciated.
Using cursor has some performance penalty,  I would prefer a better performing version but for now this works. Thanks!

Comment: inner most subquery has `select b_index, max(accu) accu` which gets the biggest accu first.

Comment: I meant getting the pair with the highest accu first, not the highest accu from the fist b_index. Not doing that can exclude the higher accu pair because a_index for that pair has been eliminated. I hope i made myself understood. That being said, i don't think i was clear about wanting that :) Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Do you mean overall?  You want to start with whatever b_index is related to the highest accu, then the next highest accu?  Instead of the way I thought which was just going in ascending order of b_index?

Comment: That would indeed be a little different.  Regardless -- glad you got it working.  I don't know that a (nice) recursive CTE solution exists since you have to worry about the entire previous set of answers and not just the previous recursive iteration's result set.

Comment: Yes, take the b_index with the biggest accu and remember that pair, then the b_index with the second biggest accu if that pair doesent contain the a_index from previously remembered pair... and so on... I use this for address matching between two databases, makes it easier if the words in the address are spelled in a different order. The word compare function that gives the accu is a combination of LEVENSHTEIN algo and some others.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like a below corelated subquery to check each time the a exists in other groups of parent or not

```
  Select Max(aindex), 
        bindex,max(a) , b, 
     max(accunit) 
     From (Select a.index, *  from table 
      where bindex, b in (Select 1,2 from(  
        Select bindex
       , b, 
     max(accunit)
    From table group by bindex, 
     b)
        )) t group 
      by bindex, b having 
    1=max( Case when aindex <> 
          t.aindex then 1
       Else 0 end) ;
```

Comment: I dont see hot that could work, besides sql throws the following error:
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: Umm.. It shouldve worked will try to update my query